# how i can make dynamic radio button along with altertctl option in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, radio-button

I want to set alertctl along with radio buttons dynamically in ionic 3

how I can do this?

home.ts

```
 presentAlert() {

   let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Low battery',



    inputs:[
     {
        name:'radio 1',
        label:'test',
        value:'test',
        type:'radio'
      },
      {
       label:'new',
        type: 'radio',
        value:'new',
      }

    ],
    buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: () => {
              console.log('Cancel clicked');
            }
          },
          {
            text: 'OK',
            handler: (data:string) => {
              console.log('OK clicked: '+data );

            }
          }
        ]




  });
  alert.present();

}
```

> Expected Result: with dynamic data in alertctrl with radio buttons

is there any other ways to do this?? in ionic 3

Comment: Look at the parameter of create() method if you can see a json format then you know what to do

Comment: i did't get that could plz provide any examples ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found by just separate those methods with parameter

```
this.jsonData=[
      {"id":1,"label":"saw","name":"Prithivi"},
      {"id":2,"label":"saw1","name":"Abimanyu"},
      {"id":3,"label":"saw2","name":"malliga"},
     ];



presentAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create();

    alert.setTitle("Low battery");

    for(let i=0;i<this.jsonData.length;i++)
  {
   alert.addInput({type: 'radio', label: this.jsonData[i]['label'], value: this.jsonData[i]['name'], });
  }
alert.addButton({text:'ok',handler: (data:string) => {
              console.log('OK clicked: '+data );

            }});

    alert.present();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass the below JSON string inside

```
this.alertCtrl.create({
    "title": "something",
    "message": "Select option ",
    "inputs" : [
    {
        "type":"radio",
        "label":"something1",
        "value":"something1"
    },
    {
        "type":"radio",
        "label":"something2",
        "value":"something2"
    }],
   "buttons" : [
    {
        "text": "Cancel",
        "handler": "here go your handler function"
    },
    {
        "text": "Search",
        "handler": "here go your handler function"
    }]}})
```

then it should work . The string should based on the condition how many radio buttons whats name etc every thing you can pass there